# How to stop delete data when connect database?

Tags: mysql, docker

I write init.sql and use docker to run it with mysql version 5.7.34
`
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;

```
USE test;
SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+08:00';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255),
  `password` VARCHAR(255),
  `phone` VARCHAR(255),
  `email` VARCHAR(255),
  `address` VARCHAR(255),
  `dob` TIMESTAMP,
  `last_login` TIMESTAMP,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_payment`;
CREATE TABLE `user_payment` (
  `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INT,
  `payment_type` VARCHAR(255),
  `provider` VARCHAR(255),
  `account_no` VARCHAR(255),
  `expiry` TIMESTAMP,
  `is_default` BOOLEAN
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But when I try to connect with B.E. It auto deletes my database or show this error:

```
code: 'ER_INVALID_DEFAULT'
errno: 1067,
sqlMessage: "Invalid default value for 'last_login'",
sqlState: '42000',
index: 0,
sql: 'ALTER TABLE `user` CHANGE `name` `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL'
```

Why does it happen? How can I resolve it?

Resolve the problem when connect with B.E

Comment: What is B.E ?..also I don't see an ALTER TABLE in your script and do you really want to drop the tables every time>

Comment: Does your application include some sort of database-migration system that runs automatically on startup?  (In which case you probably don't need the `init.sql` script at all.)

Comment: Are you updating _to_ or _from_ 5.7.  5.6.6 (and other versions) made changes in `TIMESTAMP` that B.E. seems to not account for.